Oracle 11c REMAP_TABLESPACE
I have a question about how it would affect making a remap_tablespace, I intend to make a remap_schema and remap_tablespace at the same time when I make an impdp since I want to make a copy of a schema but this will be temporary, the tablespace that is currently there does not have enough space to contain the two schemas. I could expand it but when I delete the schema, the tablespace will be empty and taking up space unnecessarily
I have already made impdp only from schemas that is:

impdp MySchema/password remap_schema=MySchema:MyNewSchema directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=schema_NEW_01.dmp logfile=imp_schema_NEW_01.log

I did not have MyNewSchema previously created, impdp created the schema directly but in the original tablespace that MySchema had, that is what I want to avoid.
In MySchema I have two tablespaces, one for the data and the other for the indexes, each of them has two DBF files, in a specific path dedicated to the two tablespaces, it is an LVM volume.
I have thought about doing this:

impdp MySchema/password remap_schema=MySchema:MyNewSchema remap_tablespace=Data:NewData remap_tablespace=Index:NewIndex directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=schema_NEW_01.dmp logfile=imp_schema_NEW_01.log

My question is, will this command create two new tablespaces, respecting the paths of the volumes where the DBF files have to be created? Will the impdp process respect all those details?
Currently I have an empty schema and tablespace, which I have created to carry out the process, but if impdp does all that, it would have to delete the schema and the tablespace, and let impdp carry out that procedure.
Would the procedure I have shown be correct?

Solve my doubt, the only thing is to eliminate the schema and use the impdp command explained in the question. Everything worked correctly, the new schema created was transferred to the new tablespaces and they remained by default in the schema
